# How to make ng-model dynamic?

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a dynamic registration form [My dynamic form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6VCv.png). The data written in those inputs will be later sent to some API.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in CustomRegistrationForm"
    class="form-group text-field-para" style="margin: 10px">
    <input type="{{item.Type}}" id="{{'A'+$index}}" 
           class="form-control" name="{{TmpName}}"
           ng-model="RegistationSubscriberData.User.CustomRegistrationForm[$index].Name">
</div>
```

CustomRegistration is a JSON made like this: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=5396efadcf9d475a9fee6e558e8b807c .
By my logic ng-models would have to be set (in my case) as: "FirstName", "Email", "GSMnumber",... But it just saves as the last string in the ng-model, in [my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3Gu.png) "Name". I tried to use item.Name also but it didn't make any difference. Also if I tried to "console.log(CustomRegistration[0].Name)" it worked perfectly and output "FirstName"

Can someone explain to me why in this case my 'type' works perfectly (Dynamicly) but ng-model can't work with dynamic variable. This is my first question here so if I made any mistakes I apologise in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by " it just saves as the last string in the ng-model" ?and you are storing input value in name variable so I don't see any problem what were you expecting?

Comment: CustomRegistrationForm[0].Name == FirstName,  CustomRegistrationForm[1].Name == LastName... I'm trying to save data dynamicly and not in the variable 'Name'.

Comment: whatever you bind in ng-model data will be stored there.ng-`model="RegistationSubscriberData.User.CustomRegistrationForm[$index].Name"` b'cos of this value is getting stored in name, and if you dont want data to be stored there why you have written this?. where do you want to store data ?

Comment: I want to store it in a different variable every loop of ng-repeat. So if I would written it staticaly it would look like : model="RegistationSubscriberData.User.FirstName", model="RegistationSubscriberData.User.GSMnumber",... And so on

Comment: Do you want to add dynamic keys to your `RegistationSubscriberData.User` ? is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create array for the **ng-model** then you can add dynamically into that array as below.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in CustomRegistrationForm" class="form-group text-field-para" style="margin: 10px">
         <input type="{{item.Type}}" id="{{'A'+$index}}"
                class="form-control" name="{{TmpName}}"
                ng-model="Users[item.Name]">
    </div>
    <p> {{Users}} </p>
</div>
```

In Controller

```
function TesyController($scope) {
 
    $scope.RegistationSubscriberData = {};

        $scope.CustomRegistrationForm = [
  {
    "Label": "First name",
    "Name": "FirstName",
    "Type": "text",
    "Mandatory": true,
    "Length": 20,
    "showPlaceHolder": false,
    "Regex": "/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i",
    "Validator": "",
    "requireRetypePassword": false,
    "strengthValidatorEnabled": false,
    "strengthComplexityLevel": false,
    "Format": ""
  },
  {
    "Label": "Email",
    "Name": "Email",
    "Type": "email",
    "Mandatory": true,
    "Length": "",
    "showPlaceHolder": false,
    "Regex": "",
    "Validator": false,
    "requireRetypePassword": false,
    "strengthValidatorEnabled": false,
    "strengthComplexityLevel": false,
    "Format": ""
  },
  {
    "Label": "Phone number (international format)",
    "Name": "GSMNumber",
    "Type": "text",
    "Mandatory": false,
    "Length": "",
    "showPlaceHolder": false,
    "Regex": "/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i",
    "Validator": "",
    "requireRetypePassword": false,
    "strengthValidatorEnabled": false,
    "strengthComplexityLevel": false,
    "Format": ""
  },
  {
    "Label": "Password",
    "Name": "password",
    "Type": "password",
    "Mandatory": true,
    "Length": "",
    "showPlaceHolder": false,
    "Regex": "",
    "Validator": false,
    "requireRetypePassword": true,
    "strengthValidatorEnabled": true,
    "strengthComplexityLevel": false,
    "Format": ""
  }
]
}
```

For reference you can refer below fiddle links

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrQ77/2088/)
[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLRJ/2/)

Hope this will help you.